# HTML Layout over background DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the layout in the image below. The `hidden-container` div is positioned at 0, 0 on the parent `main-container` div and shown on button click.

I have done [a mock up fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/qsyh2rrq/). The col size is smaller so it is easier to see in the fiddle.

```css
.content {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

#main-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

#hidden-container {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1047;
}

#plyr-container {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1048;
  background-color: red;
}

#info-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1048;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

#plyra,
#plyrb {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1049;
}

#plyra {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

#plyrb {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div id="main-container">

    <div id="hidden-container">

      <div id="plyr-container">
        <div id="plyra"></div>
        <div id="plyrb"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="info-container"></div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Unable to understand. Can you simplify?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand you. What do you need simplyfying?

Comment: I didn't get what you need to achieve

Comment: Sorry I am totally screwed up with positioning the structure over the background div. I want to generate the structure inside of CONTAINER so that is fits 100% to a parent div. This structure is hidden/shown by button click. I am simplifying the JSFIDDLE now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this as an example you could even do that using `display:inline-block`, along-with `css calc() function` to `minus` the `width` of `300px` from overall container to align `two column` i.e `col1` and `col2` as below,

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 0;
}

#container > .col1 {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container > .col1 > .c1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container > .col1 > .c2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container > .col2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @fmt your solutions is good, except with `font-size: 0` no text appears in the RHS column. If I remove this css line, the RHS column drops below the RHS column.

Comment: @TheRealPapa To align div that are display:inline-block, I need to set font-size:0 as by default there used be white gap between divs when they are aligned as inline-block, so check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w5yz1w8d/,
you just need to add vertical-align top.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using flexbox. I did some modification with changing the `#` to class instead. You have some unnecessary properties, like `z-index`, `top`, `left`. Those properties won't work unless you have `absolute` or `relative` on the element. You don't need them to position it and in this particular case they really do nothing. Is this something you where looking for?

I strongly recommend reading [this article on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about flexbox.

**DEMO:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsyh2rrq/16/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.hidden-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.plyr-container {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.info-container {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -4px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.plyra,
.plyrb {
  text-align: left;
  flex-basis: 50%; //use this instead of width
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.plyra {
  background-color: green;
}

.plyrb {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="main-container">

    <div class="hidden-container">

      <div class="plyr-container">
        <div class="plyra">a</div>
        <div class="plyrb">a</div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-container">d</div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dejan S awesome, thanks! But to be clear I am looking for all of "hidden-container" to be set at 0,0 of "main-container". So it overlays to 100% height and width once it is shown via click.

Comment: @TheRealPapa You could post all of the code needed (including js) and explain in the question what you like. I'm thinking you are referring to the `top` and `left` values? Then you need to put `position: relative;` on the parent element and `position: absolute;` on the element you want to take up the full height and width.